# Reading MySQL DATETIME directly from MYD file

Tags: mysql, datetime, binaryfiles

For corruption recovery issues, I have to retrieve dates from a table which I only have the .MYD file for.

The MySQL internals tells me that DATETIME:s are stored in 8 bytes:

DATETIME: Eight bytes: A four-byte integer for date packed as YYYY×10000 + MM×100 + DD and a four-byte integer for time packed as HH×10000 + MM×100 + SS

I have a known date of "2010-02-09 19:57:58", in the .MYD file this is represented by:

EE 3A D4 F1 47 12 00 00

"2010-02-05 14:24:17" is 91 61 96 F1 47 12 00 00

And so on.

However I cannot find any more documentation on how to actually convert these values to human readable dates. I read somewhere that the value is actually a timestamp with number of days since 1900-01-01, but I cannot find that right now.

How to parse these values as human readable dates?

Comment: Here are some internal specs http://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/date-and-time-data-type-representation.html

Comment: Also, data is stored as little endian.